# eslint object-curly-newline conflicts prettier multi-line rationale

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, prettier

I'm new in prettier + typescript + eslint.
Most of the integration works fine but multi-line in destructure object is not.

**Prettier 1.19.1**
[Playground link](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEACVkoGcauAHSnXTAEsBHAGkONQBMAnAQwHdSoBzAWQQFcANakWKNW7bnwCaQ2ljgAbOGHh0AIszacZqAL6oAvKhwQGcAHRgAFkwYwAyjBNwA3CEogIABxiloWZKA2DBAsAAo2CP4oTABuEKR0biAARsxgANZw9p5MZJzIMAy8cO6WMAC28gDqlqTwWDlgcHaRdaQxdQCeyOBY-u7scrahzBzlTMgAZkzycu4AVlgAHgBCaZn2TOVwADLscFMzcyCLS3biigCKvBDwh7MlIDkMQz3JTMkKSZ4M7DBVCRglmQAA4AAzuH4QORVZieHo-OBDGIHdzkG7wEZeKIgJhYAC0UDgcDoJKSpnRpFMIyYYwmSGmD3ccnKpAKRUeWAucGutwODKOjxgHwBdCByAATO5CkxSPJxABhCDlcY9KDQVEgXhyAAqHyijOOMWKAEkoKTYHYwL9vABBc0OTqKe5yHQ6IA)

**Input:**

```
const {
  ciq,
  drawingMenuX,
  drawingMenuY,
  selectedDrawing,
} = store.chartStore;
```

**Output:**

```
const { ciq, drawingMenuX, drawingMenuY, selectedDrawing } = store.chartStore;
```

**Expected behavior:**

```
const {
  ciq,
  drawingMenuX,
  drawingMenuY,
  selectedDrawing,
} = store.chartStore;
```

I wanna keep a multiline format in destructure object like the rationale (https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#multi-line-objects)

It works well in a normal object but it's not in destructure object

How can I fix this problem?
Do I just have to fix each line?

**package.json**

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.11.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.11.0",
"eslint": "^6.7.2",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^6.7.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.19.1",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.17.0",
"eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
"prettier": "^1.19.1",
```

**.eslintrc.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  extends: ['plugin:react/recommended', 'plugin:prettier/recommended', 'airbnb'],
  plugins: ['react', '@typescript-eslint'],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
  },
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      },
    },
  },
  rules: {
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [
      1,
      {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      },
    ],

    'import/extensions': [
      'error',
      'ignorePackages',
      {
        js: 'never',
        jsx: 'never',
        ts: 'never',
        tsx: 'never',
      },
    ],

    'no-confusing-arrow': [0],
  },

  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.ts', '*.tsx'],
      rules: {
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': [2, { args: 'none' }],
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 16):

I prefer the way Prettier handles this as well.

In your `.eslintrc.js` add this to your `rules`.

```js
'object-curly-newline': 'off',
```

Comment: thank you! I wanted to line break my curly braces as best as possible for readability but I couldn't find any eslint code for `object-curly-newline` at https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-curly-newline. `Off` is the way. also, `Off` isn't in the official doc I linked :S

Answer (score 9):

I was having same issue and didn't want to turn it off completely. Fortunately, there is a configuration-option for this rule, which you can look up here [`object-curly-newline`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-curly-newline)

It allows configuring line breaks if there are line breaks inside properties, between properties and even least number of properties or even to enforce consistency (both curly braces, or neither directly enclose newlines).

Here is how I am using it:

```
/* inside .eslintrc.json */

"rules": {
  "object-curly-newline": [
    "error",
    {
      "ObjectExpression": { "consistent": true, "multiline": true },
      "ObjectPattern": { "consistent": true, "multiline": true },
      "ImportDeclaration": "never",
      "ExportDeclaration": { "multiline": true, "minProperties": 3 }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my own testing, you should add the following to your `rules` in the `.eslintrc.js` (somewhat in line with GollyJer's answer)

```
'object-curly-newline': 0,
```